# compare 2 csv files only useing pandas isin function with out for loop

Tags: python, pandas

```
output = f2[~f2['column1'].isin(f1['column1'].unique())] + f2[~f2['column2'].isin(f1['column2'].unique())]
```

how to make this with an operator, i tried && and ++ also it's not working, i jut want to store the unique values from each columns to the output variable, only this way i need to do this, so i'm confused to use the operator

```
f2[~f2['column1'].isin(f1['column1'].unique())]
```

in the above command is working fine but i want to add this command again with a operator and store into one varialbe 
any solutions.??

Comment: Hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: @jezrael bro finally i got the answer ( almost tried each symbols from the keyboard)  :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
f1 = pd.read_csv('Big_1.csv',dtype=str)
f2 = pd.read_csv('Big_2.csv',dtype=str)
output= f2[~f2['column1'].isin(f1['column1'].unique()) | 
           ~f2['column2'].isin(f1['column2'].unique()) |
           ~f2['column3'].isin(f1['column3'].unique())]
print(output)
df=pd.DataFrame(output)
df.to_csv('Unique_values_only.csv',header=True,index=True)
```

we can use the

~f2['column2'].isin(f1['column2'].unique())

this method to multiple times when we give an

'|'

symbol ,in case we use operators like + or ++ or & and && will not return the 'values' from dataframe every values will be 'Nan' ,so we can check each columns and return the uniq content from the csv files , this way we can compare 2 csv files without merging.